# R: cumulative total at a daily level

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series

I have the following dataset:

[image]

I want to measure the cumulative total at a daily level. So the result look something like:

[image]

I can use dplyr's cumsum function but the count for "missing days" won't show up. As an example, the date 1/3/18 does not exist in the original dataframe. I want this missed date to be in the resultant dataframe and its cumulative sum should be the same as the last known date i.e. 1/2/18 with the sum being 5.

Any help is appreciated! I am new to the language.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Additionally, please do not post an image of data: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272

Comment: Simply create a vector of dates by day from the first day in your dataset to the last and then join it to your original data. Then you should be ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

I'll use this second `data.frame` to fill out the missing dates:

```
daterange <- data.frame(Date = seq(min(x$Date), max(x$Date), by = "1 day"))
```

Base R:

```
transform(merge(x, daterange, all = TRUE),
          Count = cumsum(ifelse(is.na(Count), 0, Count)))
#          Date Count
# 1  2018-01-01     2
# 2  2018-01-02     5
# 3  2018-01-03     5
# 4  2018-01-04     5
# 5  2018-01-05    10
# 6  2018-01-06    10
# 7  2018-01-07    10
# 8  2018-01-08    11
# ...
# 32 2018-02-01    17
```

`dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
x %>%
  right_join(daterange) %>%
  mutate(Count = cumsum(if_else(is.na(Count), 0, Count)))
```

---

Data:

```
x <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(c("1/1/18", "1/2/18", "1/5/18", "1/8/18", "2/1/18"), format="%m/%d/%y"),
                Count = c(2,3,5,1,6))
```